# how to give a download link for generated reported pdf in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, python-2.7

I have generated a PDF report from the database by the code below in `views.py`

```
 resp = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
 txn = transaction.objects.order_by('user', 'id')
 report = txn_reports(queryset=txn)
 print report
 report.generate_by(PDFGenerator, filename='filename.pdf')'
```

this PDF file is getting saved in project folder, I don't need that, I want it to prompt the user where to save the file.

I want to give a download option for this PDF in the client's browser. How do I give a "Save As" feature for this file in HTML so that the client can download it in PDF format

Answer (score 1):

Take the PDF data and send as HttpReponse.

I've done something like this in the past, generating reports with pisa:

```
template = get_template("my_template.html")
context = Context({"data": report_data})
html  = template.render(context)
result = StringIO.StringIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)
if not pdf.err:
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
```

What really matters to you is the last line, where we return the HttpResponse with the pdf document. User's browser will then prompt him to save it or maybe display it if supported.

Comment: i am using reporting in django, with that i have created report as pdf and file is getting saved automatically in my project folder, i don't need that instead want to save that file in a temporary area and pass it to the user

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is send this pdf as HttpResponse to the browser, the browser will automatically open the pdf and offer the user a way to save it.

Comment: i am using reporting in django, with that i have created report as pdf and file is getting saved automatically in my project folder, i don't need that instead want to save that file in a temporary area and pass it to the user